# Syntax Error near "CHANGE" in sqlite3

Tags: python, mysql, database, sqlite

I am attempting to execute the following (move a column to be the first one)

```
import sqlite3
db = sqlite3.connect('adatabase.sqlite')
c = db.cursor()
c.execute('ALTER TABLE tab1 CHANGE COLUMN r r def FIRST')
```

Unfortunately I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
OperationalError: near "CHANGE": syntax error
```

What could be? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*SQLite* does not support a `CHANGE COLUMN` feature; if any.

> Only the `RENAME TABLE` and `ADD COLUMN` variants of the `ALTER TABLE`
>   command are supported

See all missing features: [SQL Features That SQLite Does Not Implement](http://www.sqlite.org/omitted.html)